# MySQL: Select id if not repeated exactly 4 times

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering what is the right way to display all id_product if is NOT repeated 4 time.
This is my table:

```
id_product  id_related
    55          1
    55          2
    55          3
    55          4
    11          1
    11         123
    11          12
    36          12
    36          9
    36          14
    36          654
```

I need to find products without added 4 related products. 
In this case the result i expect is 11.

Comment: "Exactly" works both ways? So if count if 5, then include that in result too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that

```
select id_product, count(*)
from <table>
group by id_product
having count(*) < 4
```

Comment: +1 . . . This seems to come closest to what the OP wants, although s/he doesn't request the `count(*)` and the inequality probably should be `<> 4`.

Comment: You two should both get points for this one!
First, i was looking only for < then 4 to find out witch products must be done.
But when i tray with inequality <> 4 i find out some duplicated records. Good job guys!

Answer (score 2):

Following query

```
SELECT id_product
FROM table
GROUP BY id_product
HAVING COUNT(id_product) < 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
p.id_product,
p.id_related
from product p
join
(
  select 
  id_product,
  count(id_related) as tot
  from product
  group by id_product
  having tot <> 4
)p1
on p1.id_product = p2.id_product
```

If you want to filter out duplicate id_related meaning multiple occurrence of same id_related is counted as one you can use distinct as

```
count(distinct id_related)
```

Comment: As OP has not answered the question raised by @Alma Do the logic `<> 4` is partially right